# Derivative of implicit functions

Tags: implicit-differentiation

This problem got me confused. I'm supposed to find the value of the derivative of $$y\mathrm{e}^y=\mathrm{e}^{x+1}$$ at the point $x=0$.

I did find the derivate but I can't find its value because the derivate is $$\frac{y}{y+1}.$$ So basically there is no $x$ to plug in.

Comment: when $x=0$, what is $y$? And please  use latex

Comment: It doesnt mention anything about y,just x.

Answer (score 0):

we get $$y'e^{y}+ye^{y}y'=e^{x+1}$$ so $$y'=\frac{e^{x+1}}{e^y(y+1)}$$ for $$y+1\neq 0$$

Comment: Yes,i got to this point.what i wanted to know is how can i find the value of y' at the point x=0.

Comment: we have $$y(0)e^{y(0)}=e$$

Comment: from here we get $$y(0)=1$$

Answer (score 0):

You are ok. The left side of your equation is an increasing function of y and if x=0  the right side is 1 and the left side is 1 only at y=1. $\frac{y}{y+1}$ =$\frac{1}{2}$